# Numpy - find rows where all elements are finite

Tags: python, numpy

I have data which are stored in a numpy array with n rows and p columns.

I would like to check which rows are fully finite and store this information in a boolean array to use it as a mask somewhere.

I have solved it for the p=2 case, but would like to solve it for all cases

My code looks like this:

```
raw_test = np.array([[0, numpy.NaN], [0, 0], [numpy.NaN, numpy.NaN]])
test = np.isfinite(raw_test)
def multiply(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]

numpy.apply_along_axis(multiply, 1, test)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `numpy.isnan` to check which of the items are `NaN` and then find the indices of the rows which with all `True`'s using `numpy.all` and `numpy.where`.

```
>>> np.isnan(raw_test)
array([[False,  True],
       [False, False],
       [ True,  True]], dtype=bool)
>>> np.all(np.isnan(raw_test), axis=1)
array([False, False,  True], dtype=bool)
>>> np.where(np.all(np.isnan(raw_test), axis=1))[0]
array([2])
```

Comment: This does not exactly answer the question. (Negative) infinity is not NaN, but also not finite. `np.isfinite` considers (-)inf but `np.isnan` does not.  The answer below (with the masked array) works for both NaN and infinity values.

Answer (score 4):

Another option is to use a masked_array:

```
import numpy as np

raw_test = np.array([[0, np.NaN], [0, 0], [np.NaN, np.NaN]])
test = np.ma.masked_invalid(raw_test)
print(test)
# [[0.0 --]
#  [0.0 0.0]
#  [-- --]]

def multiply(x):
    return x[0] * x[1]

print(np.apply_along_axis(multiply, 1, test))
```

yields

```
[ nan   0.  nan]
```